# Phusion Passenger Doesn't compile in Mountain Lion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xcode, passenger, osx-mountain-lion

I am having trouble compiling Phusion Passenger with my new OSX Mountain Lion Install. Do you have any advice?

```
Installing Phusion Passenger Standalone...
[*******************************              ] Compiling Phusion Passenger... 
*** ERROR: the following command failed:
mkdir -p 'ext/ruby/ruby-1.9.3-x86_64-macosx/'
cd 'ext/ruby/ruby-1.9.3-x86_64-macosx/' && /Users/boris/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p194@apps2/ruby '/Users/boris/.passenger/standalone/3.0.13-x86_64-ruby1.9.3-macosx-10.8/support/ext/ruby/extconf.rb'
checking for alloca.h... *** /Users/boris/.passenger/standalone/3.0.13-x86_64-ruby1.9.3-macosx-10.8/support/ext/ruby/extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=/Users/boris/.passenger/standalone/3.0.13-x86_64-ruby1.9.3-macosx-10.8/support/ext/ruby
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/boris/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby
/Users/boris/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:381:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /Users/boris/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:506:in `try_cpp'
    from /Users/boris/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:931:in `block in have_header'
    from /Users/boris/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:790:in `block in checking_for'
    from /Users/boris/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /Users/boris/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from /Users/boris/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block in postpone'
    from /Users/boris/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from /Users/boris/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `postpone'
    from /Users/boris/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:789:in `checking_for'
    from /Users/boris/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:930:in `have_header'
    from /Users/boris/.passenger/standalone/3.0.13-x86_64-ruby1.9.3-macosx-10.8/support/ext/ruby/extconf.rb:36:in `<main>'
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [cd 'ext/ruby/ruby-1.9.3-x86_64-macosx/' &&...]
/Users/boris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:53:in `block in create_shell_runner'
/Users/boris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `call'
/Users/boris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `sh'
/Users/boris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:39:in `sh'
/Users/boris/.passenger/standalone/3.0.13-x86_64-ruby1.9.3-macosx-10.8/support/build/ruby_extension.rb:43:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/boris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/Users/boris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/Users/boris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/Users/boris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/Users/boris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/boris/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/boris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/boris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:176:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/boris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `each'
/Users/boris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/boris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:157:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/boris/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/boris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/boris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:176:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/boris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `each'
/Users/boris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/boris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:157:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/boris/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/boris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/boris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:176:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/boris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `each'
/Users/boris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/boris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:157:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/boris/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/boris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/boris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/Users/boris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
/Users/boris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/boris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
/Users/boris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
/Users/boris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/boris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/Users/boris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
/Users/boris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/boris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/Users/boris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/boris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@apps2/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/Users/boris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@apps2/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => nginx => native_support => ext/ruby/ruby-1.9.3-x86_64-macosx//passenger_native_support.bundle => ext/ruby/ruby-1.9.3-x86_64-macosx//Makefile
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Looks like you're using RVM. So go ahead and recompile ruby

> rvm uninstall 1.9.3 
>     rvm install 1.9.3

1. Reinstall the passenger Gem
2. Make sure to include the .conf files for your virtual hosts, which the upgrade to Mountain Lion probably clobbered

In my case I added the following line to the end of my `httpd.conf` file:

```
Include /etc/apache2/passenger_pane_vhosts/*.conf
```

Comment: your ruby command helped fixed my postgres gem issue on Mountain Lion as well.  Thanks broham.

Answer (score 1):

The root cause is that gcc-4.2 cannot be found. In my case gcc 4.2.1 was installed but just called `gcc` so I linked `gcc-4.2` to `gcc` and this allowed me to install Passenger.  The command line is `sudo ln /usr/bin/gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.2`

I had reinstalled Ruby via rvm and re-downloaded the passenger gem before I tried this but I don't think either of these was necessary.

Comment: Thanks this did it for me, I think I also uninstalled/reinstalled more than I needed to.

Comment: If you have a homebrew g++-4.2, you can do:

<!-- language: lang-bash -->


  cd /usr/local/Cellar/apple-gcc42/4.2.1-5666.3/bin # or your version  
  ln -s g++-4.2 g++  
  sudo PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/apple-gcc42/4.2.1-5666.3/bin:$PATH passenger-install-apache2-module  
  rm g++

Comment: Ugh, sorry for the bad formatting above.  I'm on a slow connection and I passed the five minutes mark. :/

Answer (score 1):

You may also encounter this problem if you install a binary version of rvm. You can also try:

```
rvm uninstall 1.9.3-p327
rvm install 1.9.3-p327 --disable-binary
```

Once that's done, you should be able to compile Phusion Passenger without issue. Or at least without running into *this* issue.